# References: convergence rates of kernel regression, exchangeable data

Tags: nonparametric, convergence, asymptotics, nonparametric-regression

I have been studying Kernel estimation; in particular, the Nadaraya-Watson estimator. I am interested in studying the rate of convergence in L^p of the NW (or similar) estimators for subgaussian variables. In other words, I would like to study the following problem.

Let $(X,Y)$ be random variables in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with joint density $\mu(x,y)$. We can assume $\mu$ to be k times differentiable, and $Y$ and $X$ to be subgaussian (i.e. they have every moment). Let $f(x) = \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X=x]$. Let $\hat{f}_n$ be a kernel estimator of $f$ as a function of a sample of size $n$ (e.g. $\hat{f}_n is the NW estimator), with an i.i.d. sample.

My main questions are:

1. What is the rate of convergence of $\|\hat{f}_n-f\|_p$ to zero? In other words, what is the rate of convergence  in $L^P$ of the estimator?
2. Is there an equivalent result to the ergodic theorem if we assume that the sample is exchangeable instead of i.i.d.?

Thanks.